# How to write a complete web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, architecture

These questions were asked me in a technical interview:

- If we deploy an application on multiple server (like database server, web server) then, each request should be redirected to proper server, then how you will handle it in your code?
- How security pinholes will be handled in an application?
- What things should be considered while writing a web application?
- How will you do load/performance testing of web application? Which framework you will use for it?
- How will you implement a cache for results which require a DB access?

Please let me know how to write an web application considering all these points. I am not so much aware of architechural design of web application.
Your guidelines will be helpful.

Comment: ... are you basically asking us to answer your interview question? (I'm also assuming it's not an on-the-spot question... or you're just very good at under the desk phone-typing...). If you cannot answer these questions, it sounds, I'm afraid, like you're not qualified for that job...

Comment: This is a very broad and open-ended question, and the goal of asking it was probably to get an idea of how you *think* it would be done, since there are lots of ways of doing it. When being asked such an open-ended question it's a good idea to just start describing what you think the correct answer is, ask for clarification or more requirements, and always consider the advantages and disadvantages of the decisions you've made.

Comment: This is a very open ended question, and as an interview question this is your opportunity to talk about your experiences and show your understanding of web applications - I doubt that the interviewer was expecting any sort of solid or definitive answer.

Comment: You really might want to ask those in separate questions; each of them will take a long answer on a good day.

Comment: as suggested by others, they are vague questions and have way too many answers.
i'd search for each of those questions on google (say) and read up articles related on it. maybe try code up a few things. also consider reading design of apache webserver. that should give you a good insight on a lot of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than give you an answer to an interview question, I'll point you in the right direction.  This is important stuff to know, so to be better prepared for your next interview, you'll want to study.  The problem sounds like you don't even know where to start.

Distributing your web app across multiple servers is done for Load Balancing.  It's not entirely a development issue, but as a developer you do need to be aware of some things.

I'd start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) and then google "load balancing asp.net" for further reading.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for ur direction. I will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I can only answer your question like this:

- look at how others do it
- look at popular frameworks for the platforms you're willing to use, try understanding what they do, why they do it, and how they accomplish it
- read a lot
- try hard yourself
- learn from the numerous mistakes you will make

You cannot get experience from our answers, nor from books. Only by doing things.

For starters, you may rather want to set up a website using a popular open source CMS of your choice, work with it, and learn about configuration etc. Then start writing pluggins and then - like any developer - become convinced that you can do it MUCH better than anyone else. And once you're done with that phase, you're good to go ;)

greetz
back2dos